# writing my own log data type haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell and I'm writing a program in which I want to have a log message with the creation time and having the possibilty to appand text to the current msg so that only the message will change but the time will stay the time of creation.
I tried to do the following:

```
 data Msg = MNothing | MJust UTCTime String
```

`M` is for Message, and the reason for the `MNothing` is so there will be a possibility for an empty message.

I also wrote:

```
instance Monoid Msg where
    mempty = MNothing
    (MJust t s) `mappend` (MJust t' s') = MJust (minimum (t,t'))  (s++s')
```

This way I can use `mappend` for two messages and it will take the earliest time from the messages.

My problems are:

1. With the Msg type, I'm having trouble creating an `MJust` variable, the reason is that calling `getCurrentTime` returns `IO UTCTime` , and I want to have `UTCTime`. How can I solve this?
2. I can only `concat` two Msgs, but it is kind of pointless to do so, is it possible to be able to concat `Msg` with normal `String` (or `[Char]`)?

I'm new to Haskell so maybe I'm missing something? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you've not yet covered some fundamental topics in Haskell, particularly monads. I'd recommend avoiding `IO` until you've at least read the [learn you a Haskell chapter on it](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output), or even the [chapter on monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).

Answer (score 4):

> With the Msg type, I'm having truble creating a MJust variable, the
>   reason is that calling getCurrentTime returns IO UTCTime , and I want
>   to have UTCTime . How can I solve this?

There exist a number of functions for `IO` that help solve these "mismatches"
 (they are more general and work for other types as well, but that doesn't concern us now.)

The important idea is that you don't extract values out of `IO`. Instead of that, you "lift" functions to work *inside* `IO`!

For example, the [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) function (also called [`liftA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA)) transforms a function so that it works inside `IO`:

> ```
> fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
> ```

[`liftA2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) let's you apply a two-argument function to arguments that live inside `IO`:

> ```
> liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO b -> IO c
> ```

[`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) (also called [`pure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure)) lets you put any value inside `IO`:

> ```
> return :: a -> IO a
> ```

In your case, you could create a value of type `IO Msg` like this

> ```
> liftA2 MJust getCurrentTime (pure "somestring")
> ```

Remember, you don't get the `UTCTime` out of `IO`. Instead, you bring everything you need inside `IO`.

There also exists the more flexible function/operator [`(>>=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62--61-) (called "bind") that lets you build composite `IO` operations in which the second operation depends on a value returned by the first one:

> ```
> (>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
> ```

Notice that we can decide what `IO b` to perform based on the result of the `IO a`.

A trivial example:

```
getLine >>= \msg -> if msg == "foo" then putStr "yay" else putStr "nay"
```

And again the `IO Msg`:

```
getCurrentTime >>= \theTime -> pure (MJust theTime "foo")
```

Using `(>>=)` we can construct sequences of operations that are quite similar to blocks of statements in an imperative language. But writing all those `(>>=)` can get unwidely, so there is a bit of syntactic sugar called [do-notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) that makes things easier.

The `IO Msg` in do-notation:

```
do theTime <- getCurrentTime 
   pure (MJust theTime "foo")
```

Here the `<-` is not an actual operator like `(>>=)` but part of the syntactic sugar.

Comment: As for b) you could simply write a function with type `String -> Msg -> Msg` outside of the `Monoid` "interface".

Comment: Thanks. Your commnet really helped!.
I have just one question: you said I can write : `getCurrentTime >>= \theTime -> pure (MJust theTime "foo")` I want to maybe create my own monad so I can use the >>= in order to concatinate msgs together (I think it will be better than using the monoid and `mappend`.
Do you think I can do that? and if I can, what do I need to succeed?

Comment: @DvirItzko Your `Msg` type doesn't fit `Monoid` because times are difficult to "smash togeter". Perhaps you simply could use a list `[Msg]`? Lists are automatically monoids.

There already is a type called `Writer` that let's you accumulate a monoidal "log" as a side effect of doing other things http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html#t:Writer If you want to perform IO stuff as well you'll need the "transformer" variant: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html#t:WriterT

Comment: @DvirItzko See also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers  and http://adit.io/posts/2013-06-10-three-useful-monads.html#the-writer-monad

Comment: @danidaiz I'm having trouble with your answer. Now that I get IO Msg instead of Msg object, I'm not sure what to do with it.
For example, I want to use putStrLn on it. 
Before I used bind,  I just implemented the Show Msg and the I called `putStrLn show msg`
But now it doesn't work because it returns IO Msg and not Msg.

Comment: I don't have a problem with "smash together" time because I can do something like this:
`instance Monoid (Msg a) where
    mempty  = MNothing
    (MJust t s) `mappend` (MJust t' s') = MJust (minimum (t,t'))  (s++s')`
Meaning I decided to take to minumum of times and just append the string. The problem is that it doesn't work and I'm trying to understand why

Comment: @DvirItzko `putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()`. You can use `(>>=)` to combine it with your `IO Msg`, and get a value of type `IO ()` in return, that, when executed, will construct a `Msg` and then print it. Remember that `main` is a value of type `IO ()` in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

As for (2), the way I would solve this is to make `Msg` a `Functor`:

```
data Msg a = MNothing | MJust UTCTime a

instance Functor Msg where
    fmap f MNothing = MNothing
    fmap f (MJust t x) = MJust t (f x)
```

Then to concat with a string you can use `fmap`:

```
msg' = fmap (++ " in bed") msg
```

Comment: I have a problem . Now I can't use Show to see the message. 
before I had 
`instance Show (Msg a) where
    show (MNothing) = ""
    show (MJust t s) = show t ++ s`
But now it doesn't work, I get:
`    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at Server.hs:41:10
    Relevant bindings include
      s :: a (bound at Server.hs:43:19)
      show :: Msg a -> String (bound at Server.hs:42:5)
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘s’
    In the expression: show t ++ s`

Comment: I wouldn't use `show` for this, which generally outputs valid Haskell code -- just use `deriving (Show)` on the data decl.  Then for your custom render define `renderMsg :: Msg String -> String`.